# Is there a R function to transform a list of lists of lists to a list of lists of vectors?

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a list of lists of lists, and I want to transform it to a list of lists where elements will be vectors.

In details, `l: list of 180 elements`, `l[[1]]: list of 12 elements` and `l[[1]][[1]]: list of 20 elements`, each one has a name with one value. How can get one list of 12 elements, where each element is a list of 20 vectors, each vector contains 180 elements.

Instead of calling, `mapply(c,l[[1]][[1]]$id, l[[2]][[1]]$id, .... l[[180]][[1]]$id, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)` and repeating this for each key, Is there any way to do this inside a loop?

Example:

```
> a<-list(1,'a',1.2)
> b<-list(2,'b',0.1)
> d<-list(3,'d',3)
> e<-list(4,'e',0.1)
> x<-list(a,b)
> y<-list(d,e)
> z<-list(x,y)
```

The desired output:

```
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 1 3
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 'a' 'd'
#>
#> [[1]][[3]]
#> [1] 1.2 3
#>
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 2 4
#>
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 'b' 'e'
#>
#> [[2]][[3]]
#> [1] 0.1 0.1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try nested `Map` like below

```
z <- Map(function(...) Map(c,...), x,y)
```

such that

```
> z
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "a" "d"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 1.2 3.0


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2 4

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "b" "e"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 0.1 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just nest `lapply`.

**Sample data:**

```r
a <- list(1, 2, 3)
b <- list(a, a)
x <- list(b, b)
x
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[1]][[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[1]][[1]][[3]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [[1]][[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]][[3]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [[2]][[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]][[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]][[1]][[3]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [[2]][[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]][[3]]
#> [1] 3
```

Now just call `unlist` via nested `lapply` functions:

```
lapply(x, function(x) lapply(x, unlist))
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: these lists have the same length, and I want to transform them to lists of vectors.

Comment: @Cecile this takes a list of list of lists, and transforms it to a list of list of vectors. That's exactly what your stated aim was. This will work whatever the length of the lists. If this isn't what you had in mind, could you perhaps expand your question, perhaps with a toy example and expected output? I'm sure we could help.